# Multiple apps in single K8S deployment

Tags: kubernetes, deployment

I'm exploring K8S possibilities and I'm wonder is there any way to create deployments for two or more apps in single deployment so it is transactional - when something is wrong after deployment all apps are rollbacked. Also I want to mention that **I'm not saying about pod with multiple containers** because additional side car containers are rather intended for some crosscutting concerns like monitoring, authentication (like kerberos) and others but it is not recommended to put different apps in single pod. Having this in mind, is it possible to have single deployment that can produce 2+ kind of pods?

Comment: That's more or less the problem [helm](https://helm.sh) is designed to solve, with the asterisk that what "rollback" does in up to you, deleting the release entirely, or trying to `helm upgrade --version $old_version` in cases of failure

Comment: You may put the preparatory tasks in the init container and it that fails, the rest of the containers will not be created. but you will have to still rollback manually.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it possible to have single deployment that can produce 2+ kind of pods?

No.  A Deployment creates only one kind of Pod.  You can update a Deployment's contents, and it will incrementally replace existing Pods with new ones that match the updated Pod spec.

Nothing stops you from creating multiple Deployments, one for each kind of Pod, and that's probably the approach you're looking for here.

> ... when something is wrong after deployment all apps are rollbacked.

Core Kubernetes doesn't have this capability on its own; indeed, it has somewhat limited capacity to tell that something has gone wrong, other than a container failing its health checks or exiting.

Of the various tools in [@SYN's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71546490) I at least have some experience with Helm.  It's not quite "transactional" in the sense you might take from a DBMS, but it does have the ability to manage a collection of related resources (a "release" of a "chart") and it has the ability to roll back an entire version of a release across multiple Deployments if required.  See the [`helm rollback` command](https://docs.helm.sh/docs/helm/helm_rollback/).

Answer (score 2):

### Helm

As pointed out in comments, one way to go about this would be to use something like Helm.

Helm is some kind of client (as of v3. Previous also involved "tiller", a controller running in your kubernetes cluster: let's forget about that one/deprecated).

Helm uses "Charts" (more or less: templates, with default values you can override).

### Kustomize

Another solution, similar to Helm, is Kustomize. Working from plain-text files (not templates), while making it simple to override / customize your objects before applying them to your Kubernetes cluster.

### ArgoCD

While Kustomize and Helm are both standalone clients, we could also mention solutions such as ArgoCD.

The ArgoCD controller would run inside your Kubernetes cluster, allowing you to create "Application" objects.

Those Applications are processed by ArgoCD, driving deployment of your workloads (common sources for those applications would involve Helm Charts, Git repositories, ...).

The advantage of ArgoCD being that their controller may (depending on your configuration) be responsible for upgrading your applications over time (eg: if your source is a git repository, branch XXX, and someone pushes changes into that branch: argocd would apply those pretty much right away)

### Operators

Although most of those solutions are pretty much unaware of how your application is running. Say you upgrade a deployment, driven by Helm, Kustomize or ArgoCD, and end up with some database pods stuck in crashloopbackoff: your application pods would get updated nevertheless, there's no automatic rollback to a previous working configuration.

Which brings us to another way to ship applications to Kubernetes: operators.

Operators are aware of the state of your workloads, and may be able to fix common errors ( depending on how it was coded, ... there's no magic ).

An operator is an application (can be in Go, Java, Python, Ansible playbooks, ... or whichever comes with some library communicating with a Kubernetes cluster API)

An operator is constantly connected to your Kubernetes cluster API. You would usually find some CustomResourceDefinitions specific to your operator, allowing you to describe the deployment of some component in your cluster. (eg: the elasticsearch operator introduces an object kind "ElasticSearch", and some "Kibana")

The operator watches for instances of the objects it managed (eg: ElasticSearch), eventually creating Deployment/StatefulSets/Services ...
If someone deletes an object that was created by your operator, it would/should be re-created by that operator, in a timely manner (mileage may vary, depending on which operator we're talking about ...)

A perfect sample for operators would be something like OpenShift 4 (OKD4). A Kubernetes cluster that comes with 10s of operators (SDN, DNS, machine configurations, ingress controller, kubernetes API server, etcd database, ...). The whole cluster is an assembly of operators: upgrading your cluster, each of those would manage the upgrade of the corresponding services, in an orchestrated way, ... one after the other, ... if anything fails, you're still usually left with enough replicas running to troubleshoot the issue, ...

---

Depending on what you're looking for, each option has advantages and inconvenients. Now if you're looking for "single deployment that can produce 2+ kind of pods", then ArgoCD or some home-grown operator would qualify.

Comment: Thanks for detailed response. To summarize if I underwound it right - for my requirements "single deployment that can produce 2+ kind of pods" there is no build in way and I have to use third party like ArgoCD or custom code in operators. You mentioned Kustomize but as far as I know it gives some patches or inheritance structure but nothing more.

Comment: Right, I mentioned Kustomize, following on the initial Helm recommendations: but while both can create several deployments in one run, it's not exactly the same as "single deployment that can produce 2+ kind of pods". Unless I misunderstood what you meant by that? Reading this back: did you mean one deployment where two replicas would not do the same thing/using separate images? maybe?

Comment: I don't know helm yet but I feel that it will give me two separate deployments but I was asking about scenario: replicaset of component with pod type A and another replicaset of other component B - one deployment (transaction) could give me rollback when after deployment of A there is problem with communication with B and both are roll backed to previous versions (I know that they should not be thight coupled but world is not ideal ;) )